# What is a Lagrangian of a photon?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, photons, lagrangian-formalism

In sense of classical mechanics+special relativity what is lagrangian of a photon?
Lagrangian of a relativistic massive particle is as follows:
$$ L_{massive}= -mc\sqrt{c^2-v^2} $$
So is it a zero?

Comment: Concerning the Lagrangian of a massless scalar particle, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451

Answer (score 1):

Classical electrodynamics has a lagrangian for the classical fields, see [discussion here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/derivation-of-maxwells-equations-from-field-tensor-lagrangian) .

The photon is an [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and does not have a classical existence.

[Here is on page 5](http://physics.indiana.edu/~sg/p622/qft_S57-59.pdf) the Lagrangian for a photon

[image: photon langrangian]