# Lagrangian for the motion in a null geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, geodesics

The motion of a photon in the gravitational field is described by a simple condition: the four vector has zero norm.
My question is: is it possible to derive this dynamic from a Lagrangian? I was thinking to use the usual action but I have realized very soon that it applies only for massive particles.

Comment: Concerning the Lagrangian of a massless scalar particle, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451