# Lagrangian of massless particle in a potential

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, action, point-particles

There are a few questions about a Lagrangian for massless relativistic particles, notably [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107921/lagrangian-for-relativistic-massless-point-particle), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566529/massless-particles-in-the-lagrangian-formalism-of-special-relativity) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361165/lagrangian-formulation-for-lightlike-geodesics), regarding free particles in particular.

In the case of the square-root Lagrangian for massive particles, adding a potential term (such as a Coulomb potential energy) was no different to the non-relativistic case.

Is the same still true in the case of the Lagrangian without the square-root? My instinct is no, due to the difference in parameterisation and presence of the einbein. If not, is there a way to determine how the potential should be expressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let us parametrize the point particle by an arbitrary world-line (WL) parameter $\tau$ (which does not have to be the proper time).
2. Let us now address OP's question: *Yes,* even for the non-square-root Lagrangian
   $$\begin{align}L~=~&\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e}-\frac{e (mc)^2}{2} -V, \cr 
   \dot{x}^2~:=~&g_{\mu\nu}(x)~ \dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}~<~0,\cr
   \dot{x}~:=~&\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}, \end{align}\tag{A}$$
   with the einbein field $e>0$ one just subtracts the potential $V$ as usual.
3. As a consistency check (in the massive case $m>0$ and assuming that $V$ does not depend on $e$), we can integrate out the einbein field $e$ to obtain the usual square-root Lagrangian
   $$ L_0~=~ -mc\sqrt{-\dot{x}^2}-V,\tag{B}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137857/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. Geometrically, we should point out that it is implicitly assumed that the 1-forms
   $$ e\mathrm{d}\tau, \qquad V \mathrm{d}\tau, \qquad L_0\mathrm{d}\tau,  \qquad L\mathrm{d}\tau,\tag{C}$$
   (and the corresponding actions) are invariant under WL reparametrizations
   $$ \tau\longrightarrow \tau^{\prime}=f(\tau). \tag{D}$$
   In other words, the WL reparametrization (D) is a gauge symmetry. This means that one can choose a gauge-fixing condition, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130867/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373541/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377189/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
5. Concerning coexistence of square-root & non-square-root Lagrangians, see also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I tried at first, but unless I'm misunderstanding how to get the equations of motion (my assumption is that I can fix $e$ to be a constant), does the massless case not just give me a result with the same form as the fully non-relativistic case? If my assumption about the einbein is wrong, how do a choose/find what it is?

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I suppose you answered my question, so thanks very much :) I couldn't actually get a solution that made physical sense to me, so I went down the route of finding the Hamiltonian and taking the massless limit, which gave me an answer which looked plausible, such as the particle maintaining a speed of $c$.