# Fermat's principle in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action

I do know the principle of least action, but is it possible to formulate classical mechanics based on the principle of least time? That is, if we know the initial state $(x_i,p_i)$ of the particle and the external force field, then some variational problem would imply the classical path as a minimal time problem from the initial point $x_i$ to the final point $x_f$.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a fact that the [action for a free relativistic massive point particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451) happens to be (proportional to)  [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) $\tau$, which superficially sounds like the [Fermat's principle of stationary time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle).
2. However, there are important differences and shortcomings:

   - On one hand, the massive point particle action stops being proper time if we try to include forces/interactions/potentials.
   - On the other hand, the Fermat's principle uses laboratory time $t$, and it is for massless particles, namely light.
3. A more fruitful strategy is to turn OP's question on its head, and instead try to derive Fermat's principle from the [action for a relativistic massless particle in a curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107921/2451). This is done in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/461402/2451).

Comment: Thanks for answering.