# Infinitesimal transformations for a relativistic particle

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

The action of a free relativistic particles can be given by
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau \left(e^{-1}(\tau)g_{\mu\nu}(X)X^\mu(\tau)X^\nu(\tau)-e(\tau)m^2\right),\tag{1.8}$$
with signature $(-,+,\ldots,+)$. If we then make an infinitesimal transformation of the parametrization parameter $\tau$ this would be
$$\tau\to\tau^\prime=\tau-\eta(\tau),\tag{1.10}$$
for an infinitesimal parameter $\eta(\tau)$.

Of course we can describe the system as it pleases us so we know that $$X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau^\prime)=X^\mu(\tau).$$ From this relation we see that $X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau)$ must be
$$X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau)
\approxeq X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau^\prime+\eta(\tau))
\approxeq X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau^\prime)+\eta(\tau)\frac{d X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau^\prime)}{d\tau^\prime}
\approxeq X^{\mu}(\tau)+\eta(\tau)\frac{d X^{\mu}(\tau)}{d\tau}$$
Which all can be summarized as
$$\delta X^{\mu}(\tau)=X^{\mu^\prime}(\tau)-X^{\mu}(\tau)=\eta(\tau)\frac{d X^{\mu}(\tau)}{d\tau}.\tag{1.10}$$
Now this is all well I hope. But if one does the same argument for $e(\tau)$ one gets the wrong transformation. It is a scalar function so it has to obey
$$e^\prime(\tau^\prime)=e(\tau).$$ Which would give the same transformation.

The right transformation are written in [David Tong's lectures on string theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0333) on page 13, eq. (1.10).
The transformation is
$$\delta e(\tau)=\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\eta(\tau) e(\tau)\right).\tag{1.10}$$
Could someone show me how this is done and elaborate a little on how one knows how different object transforms?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I) *Passive picture.* The einbein $e$ is not an invariant but transforms as

$$ e~=~e^{\prime} \frac{d\tau^{\prime}}{d\tau}\tag{1} $$

under a reparametrization of the world-line (WL) parameter

$$ \tau\longrightarrow \tau^{\prime}=f(\tau).\tag{2} $$

In other words, $\omega:= e \mathrm{d}\tau\in \Gamma(T^{\ast}I) $
is a one-form on the 1-dimensional WL manifold $I$. The particle position

$$ x^{\mu}~=~x^{\prime \mu}\tag{3} $$

is invariant, while the particle velocity transforms as

$$ \dot{x}^{\mu}~=~\dot{x}^{\prime \mu}\frac{d\tau^{\prime}}{d\tau}.\tag{4}$$

These transformation rules (1)-(4) can be seen in many ways. One way is that the action

$$ S~=~\int \! \mathrm{d}\tau ~L , \qquad L~:=~\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2e}-\frac{e m^2}{2},\tag{5}$$

should be invariant under reparametrizations (2). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Let us call variations in the WL manifold $I$ for *horizontal* and variations in the target space (TS) for *vertical.* Then the infinitesimal horisontal variation

$$\delta_h\tau ~:=~\tau^{\prime} - \tau ~=~-\eta, \tag{6}$$

where $\eta$ is an infiniteimal parameter. More generally, the infinitesimal horisontal variation is

$$ \delta_h~\stackrel{(6)}{=}~ -\eta\frac{d}{d\tau}.\tag{7}$$

The total infinitesimal variations are

$$\begin{align} \delta x~:=~&x^{\prime}(\tau^{\prime})-x(\tau)~\stackrel{(3)}{=}~0, \cr
\delta e~:=~&e^{\prime}(\tau^{\prime})-e(\tau)~\stackrel{(1)+(6)}{=}~e\frac{d\eta}{d\tau} .  
\end{align}\tag{8}$$

The infinitesimal vertical variations

$$\delta_v~=~\delta-\delta_h\tag{9}$$

are

$$\begin{align} \delta_v x~:=~&x^{\prime}(\tau)-x(\tau)
~\stackrel{(7)+(8)+(9)}{=}~\eta\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d\tau}, \cr
\delta_v e~:=~&e^{\prime}(\tau)-e(\tau)
~\stackrel{(7)+(8)+(9)}{=}~\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta e) .  
\end{align}\tag{10}$$

II) *Active picture.* From the perspective of the 1-dimensional WL manifold $I$, the infinitesimal transformation can e.g. be encoded via [Lie derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative) ${\cal L}_Y$ wrt. a vector field

$$  Y ~=~\eta \frac{d}{d\tau}~\in~ \Gamma(TI) \tag{11} $$

on the 1-dimensional WL manifold $I$. The Lie derivatives are

$$  {\cal L}_Y x^{\mu}~=~Y[x^{\mu}]~=~\eta \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau},\tag{12} $$

$$\begin{align}   ({\cal L}_Ye)\mathrm{d}\tau~:=~&{\cal L}_Y\omega
~=~\{\mathrm{d}, i_Y\}\omega~=~\mathrm{d}i_Y\omega \cr
 ~=~&\mathrm{d}(i_Y\omega)~=~\mathrm{d}(\eta e)
~=~\mathrm{d}\tau\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta e),\end{align} \tag{13} $$

and hence

$$  {\cal L}_Ye  ~\stackrel{(8)}{=}~\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta e).\tag{14} $$

The above should be compared with eq. (1.10) in Ref. 1
$$  \tau\to \tau^{\prime}~=~\tau-\eta, \qquad
\delta_v x^{\mu}~=~\eta\frac{d x^{\mu}}{d\tau}, \qquad \delta_v e  ~=~\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta e), \tag{1.10}$$
respectively.

III) *Classical BV formulation.* Let us mention for completeness that the gauge transformation $\delta$ can be encoded as a BRST transformation, cf. e.g. Ref. 2 and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246992/2451) Phys.SE post.  Roughly speaking, the Grassmann-even gauge parameter $\eta$ is then replaced by a Grassmann-odd Faddeev-Popov (FP) ghost $C$. (Actually, the gauge parameter $\eta$ will more precisely be replaced with the combination $e^{1-r}C$, where $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is a power, to be more general, cf. eq. (26) below.) To minimize the appearances of time derivatives, instead of using the Lagrangian (5), it becomes a bit simpler to start from the Hamiltonian Lagrangian

$$L_H~:=~ p_{\mu} \dot{x}^{\mu} - H, \qquad H~:=~ eT, \qquad T~:=~\frac{1}{2}(p^2+m^2), \qquad  p^2~:=~ g^{\mu\nu}(x)~p_{\mu} p_{\nu}, \tag{21} $$

cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post.
Here we will use the [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism), cf. Ref. 3. The fields

$$  \phi^{\alpha} ~=~ \{ x^{\mu};~p_{\mu};~ e;~C;~ \bar{C};~B\} \tag{22}$$

are positions $x^{\mu}$; momenta $p_{\mu}$; einbein $e$; FP ghost $C$; FP antighost $\bar{C}$; and Lautrup-Nakanishi (LN) Lagrange multiplier $B$, respectively. They are WL tensors of contravariant orders $0$; $0$; $-1$; $r$; $0$; and $0$, respectively. Each field $\phi^{\alpha}$ has a corresponding antifield $\phi^{\ast}_{\alpha}$ of opposite Grassmann parity. The corresponding BV action$^1$

$$\begin{align} S_{BV}~=~&\int \! \mathrm{d}\tau ~L_{BV} , \cr
 L_{BV}~=~&L_H +\left(x^{\ast}_{\mu} \dot{x}^{\mu}+p_{\ast}^{\mu}  \dot{p}_{\mu} +r C^{\ast}\dot{C}  \right)e^{r-1}C +\underbrace{e^r C\dot{e}^{\ast}}_{\sim~e^{\ast}\frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C)}  + B \bar{C}^{\ast},\end{align} \tag{23} $$

satisfies the classical master equation

$$  (S_{BV},S_{BV})~=~0, \tag{24}$$

with [antibracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra) $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on Darboux-form, i.e. the non-zero fundamental antibrackets read

$$  (\phi^{\alpha}(\tau),\phi^{\ast}_{\beta}(\tau^{\prime}))
~=~\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}~\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}). \tag{25}$$

The Grassmann-odd nilpotent BRST transformation ${\bf s}~=~(S_{BV},\cdot)$ reads

$$\begin{align} {\bf s}x^{\mu}~=~&e^{r-1} C \dot{x}^{\mu}, \qquad 
{\bf s}p_{\mu}~=~e^{r-1} C  \dot{p}_{\mu}, \qquad 
{\bf s}e~=~ \frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C),  \cr
{\bf s}C~=~& re^{r-1} C\dot{C},\qquad 
{\bf s}\bar{C}~=~ - B,\qquad 
{\bf s}B ~=~0, \end{align} \tag{26} $$

which should be compared with eq. (1.10). The BV gauge-fixing fermion $\psi$ can be chosen on the form

$$ \psi ~:=~\int \! \mathrm{d}\tau~\bar{C}\left(\frac{\xi\rho}{2}B +\chi(e) +\epsilon \frac{d(e/\rho)}{d\tau}\right),  \tag{27} $$

where $\xi,\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ are gauge-fixing parameters, and $\rho$ is a fiducial einbein. Moreover, $\chi(e)=(e\!-\!e_0)\chi^{\prime}$ is a gauge-fixing condition (which we will assume is affine in $e$, so that the derivative $\chi^{\prime}$ is constant). The gauge-fixed Lagrangian becomes

$$\begin{align}  L_{\rm gf}~=~ &\left. L_{BV} \right|_{\phi^{\ast}
~=~\frac{\delta \psi}{\delta \phi}}\cr
~=~& L_H  +  \overbrace{\underbrace{\left(\chi^{\prime}\bar{C}-\frac{\epsilon}{\rho}\dot{\bar{C}}\right)  \frac{d}{d\tau}(e^r C)}_{
\sim~ \bar{C} \left(\chi^{\prime}+\frac{d}{d\tau}\frac{\epsilon}{\rho}\right)\frac{d}{d\tau}(e^r C)  
~\sim~ e^r C\left(\chi^{\prime}-\frac{d}{d\tau}\frac{\epsilon}{\rho}\right)\frac{d}{d\tau}\bar{C}  
}}^{\text{Faddeev-Popov term}} + \overbrace{B \left(\frac{\xi\rho}{2}B +\chi(e) +\epsilon \frac{d(e/\rho)}{d\tau}\right)}^{\text{gauge-fixing term}}, \end{align} \tag{28} $$

where the $\sim$ symbol means equality up to total time derivative terms.
The physical quantities do not depend on the choice of the gauge-fixing fermion $\psi$, as long as certain rank conditions are met.

IV) *Quantum master equation.* The odd Laplacian

$$ \Delta~=~(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int\! \mathrm{d}\tau~
\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\phi^{\alpha}(\tau)}
\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\phi^{\ast}_{\alpha}(\tau)}
~=~(-1)^{|\alpha|}\iint\! \mathrm{d}\tau~\mathrm{d}\tau^{\prime}~
\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime})\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\phi^{\alpha}(\tau)}
\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\phi^{\ast}_{\alpha}(\tau^{\prime})} \tag{29}  $$

is a singular object, which strictly speaking needs to be regularized. We calculate formally

$$ \Delta S_{BV}~\stackrel{(23)+(29)}{=}~
2(n\!-\!r)\iint\! \mathrm{d}\tau~\mathrm{d}\tau^{\prime}~
e(\tau)^{r-1}C(\tau)~
\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}) \frac{d}{d\tau}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime})
$$ $$+r \iint\! \mathrm{d}\tau~\mathrm{d}\tau^{\prime}~
e(\tau)^{r-1}\dot{C}(\tau)~\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime})^2~\neq~0,
\tag{30}  $$
where $n$ is the target space (TS) dimension. This shows that the BV action (23) does not satisfy the quantum master equation; only the classical master equation. We will discuss appropriate modifications of the BV action (23) in Section VII.

V) *Classical BFV formulation.* We identify the einbein $e\equiv \rho\lambda $, where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier. We identify $p_{\lambda}\approx\epsilon B$ with the canonical momentum of the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, and we identify the antifield $e^{\ast}\equiv \bar{P}$ with the FP ghost momentum. Introduce an ultra-local Poisson bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$ with the following canonical pairs

$$\begin{align}   \{x^{\mu}(\tau), p_{\nu}(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~&\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}\frac{1}{\rho(\tau)}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}), \qquad 
\{e(\tau)^rC(\tau), \bar{P}(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~\frac{1}{\rho(\tau)}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}), \cr
 \{\lambda(\tau), B (\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~&\frac{1}{\epsilon\rho(\tau)}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}),  \qquad 
\{\bar{C}(\tau), P(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~\frac{1}{\epsilon\rho(\tau)}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}).\end{align}\tag{31}   $$

Note the non-Darboux form

$$  \{C(\tau), \bar{P}(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~\frac{e(\tau)^{-r}}{\rho(\tau)}\delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}), \qquad
\{ B (\tau), C(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}
~=~\frac{r}{\epsilon} \frac{C(\tau)}{e(\tau)}  \delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}), \tag{32} $$

to ensure that

$$ \{e(\tau)^r C(\tau), B(\tau^{\prime})\}_{PB}~=~0. \tag{33}  $$

The BRST transformation ${\bf s}~=~\{\mathbb{Q},\cdot\}_{PB}$ (which is independent of the $\epsilon$-parameter) reads

$$\begin{align}{\bf s}x^{\mu}~=~&e^r C g^{\mu\nu}(x)p_{\nu}
~\approx~ e^{r-1} C \dot{x}^{\mu}, \cr 
{\bf s}p_{\mu}
~=~& -\frac{1}{2}e^r C \partial_{\mu}g^{\nu\lambda}(x)~p_{\nu}p_{\lambda}
~\approx~ e^{r-1} C \dot{p}_{\mu}, \cr
{\bf s}e~=~&\rho P~\approx~ \frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C) , \qquad 
 {\bf s}C~=~r\frac{C}{e}\rho P ~\approx~ re^{r-1} C\dot{C},\cr 
{\bf s}\bar{C}~=~& - B,\qquad 
{\bf s} B ~=~0, \end{align} \tag{34} $$

which should be compared with eq. (26). Here the $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eqs. of motion. The BRST transformation (34) is generated by

$$ \mathbb{Q}~:=~ \int \! \rho \mathrm{d}\tau ~Q, \qquad \{\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}\}_{PB}~=~0,\tag{35}$$

where

$$ -Q~:=~T e^r C + \epsilon B  P ~\approx~ T e^r C + \epsilon B \frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C)\tag{36}$$

is the BRST charge. The BFV action becomes

$$ S_{BFV}
~=~  \int \! \mathrm{d}\tau~\left(\dot{x}^{\mu}p_{\mu}+e^r C\dot{\bar{P}}   \right) 
-\left\{   \psi, \mathbb{Q} \right\}_{PB}
~=~ \int \! \mathrm{d}\tau ~L_{BFV} ,  \tag{37} $$

where the BFV gauge-fixing fermion $\psi$ is

$$ \psi ~:=~\int \! \mathrm{d}\tau \left(\bar{C} \left(\frac{\xi\rho}{2}B +\chi(e) +\epsilon \dot{\lambda}\right) -\bar{P}e\right),\tag{38} $$

and where the BFV Lagrangian reads$^2$

$$\begin{align} L_{BFV}~=~&\left(p_{\mu}\dot{x}^{\mu}+ e^r C\dot{\bar{P}}  \right)  
+ \epsilon\left( B \dot{\lambda} + \bar{C} \dot{P}\right)
+ \left(-eT  +\bar{C}\rho\chi^{\prime} P  +B \left(\frac{\xi\rho}{2}B+\chi(e)\right)  -\rho\bar{P}P \right)\cr
~\sim~& L_H+ \underbrace{\epsilon\left( B \dot{\lambda} + \bar{C} \dot{P}\right)}_{\text{kinetic term}}+ \bar{P}\left( \frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C)-\rho P\right) + \underbrace{\bar{C} \rho\chi^{\prime}  P}_{\text{FP term}} + \underbrace{B  \left(\frac{\xi\rho}{2}B+\chi(e)\right)}_{\text{gauge-fixing term}} \end{align} \tag{39}  .$$

VI) *Dirac bracket.* Let us integrate out the two FP momenta $P$ and $\bar{P}$.
Then the BFV Lagrangian (39) becomes the gauge-fixed Lagrangian (28) from Section III. The corresponding two [2nd class constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_class_constraint)

$$ \Theta~:=~ \rho P - \frac{d}{d\tau}( e^r C)~\approx~0, \qquad \bar{\Theta}~:=~ \rho\bar{P} - \rho\chi^{\prime} \bar{C}+\epsilon\dot{\bar{C}}~\approx~0,\tag{40}  $$

has non-zero Poisson bracket

$$ \Delta(\tau,\tau^{\prime} )
~:=~ \{\Theta(\tau),  \bar{\Theta}(\tau^{\prime}) \}_{PB}
~=~ -\left(\frac{\rho(\tau) \chi^{\prime}}{\epsilon}+2\frac{d}{d\tau} \right) \delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}),\tag{41} $$

with inverse

$$  \Delta^{-1}(\tau,\tau^{\prime} )
~=~ - \frac{1}{4} \exp\left[\frac{R(\tau^{\prime},\tau)\chi^{\prime}}{2\epsilon}\right] {\rm sgn}(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}),
\qquad R(\tau^{\prime},\tau)~:= \int_{\tau}^{\tau^{\prime}}\!\mathrm{d}\tau^{\prime\prime}\rho(\tau^{\prime\prime}). \tag{42} $$

Therefore the [Dirac bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket) becomes

$$ \{e(\tau)^rC(\tau), \bar{C}(\tau^{\prime})\}_{DB}
~=~ \frac{1}{4\epsilon} \exp\left[\frac{R(\tau^{\prime},\tau)\chi^{\prime}}{2\epsilon}\right] {\rm sgn}(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}).\tag{43} $$

Due to double time derivatives in the FP term in the gauge-fixed Lagrangian (28), it is not related to the Poisson structure (43) in a simple manner.

Note the non-Darboux form

$$\begin{align}  \{C(\tau), \bar{C}(\tau^{\prime})\}_{DB}
~=~&\frac{e(\tau)^{-r}}{4\epsilon} \exp\left[\frac{R(\tau^{\prime},\tau)\chi^{\prime}}{2\epsilon}\right] {\rm sgn}(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}) , \cr
 \{ B (\tau), C(\tau^{\prime})\}_{DB}
~=~&\frac{r}{\epsilon} \frac{C(\tau)}{e(\tau)}  \delta(\tau\!-\!\tau^{\prime}), \end{align} \tag{44}$$

to ensure that

$$  \{e(\tau)^r C(\tau), B(\tau^{\prime})\}_{DB}~=~0.\tag{45} $$

VII) *Quantum BV formulation.* Eqs. (30), (32) & (44) suggest that we should put  $r=0$, so let us do this from now on. Inspired by the BFV-BRST transformations (34), we modify the BV Lagrangian (23) into

$$ \tilde{L}_{BV}~=~L_H +x^{\ast}_{\mu}   g^{\mu\nu}(x)p_{\nu}C -\frac{1}{2}p_{\ast}^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}g^{\nu\lambda}(x)~p_{\nu}p_{\lambda} C +e^{\ast}\dot{C}  + B \bar{C}^{\ast}. \tag{46} $$

One may show that the quantum master equation is now satisfied$^1$

$$ (\tilde{S}_{BV}, \tilde{S}_{BV})~=~0~=~\Delta\tilde{S}_{BV}. \tag{47} $$

The modification (46) does not alter the gauge-fixed Lagrangian (28) apart from putting $r=0$.

References:

1. David Tong, *Lectures on String Theory,* [arXiv:0908.0333](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0333).
2. J. Polchinski, *String Theory,* Vol. 1, 1998; Section 4.2.
3. M. Henneaux and C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994; Chapter 17.
4. F. Bastianelli, [*Constrained hamiltonian systems and relativistic particles*](http://www-th.bo.infn.it/people/bastianelli/ft-16.html), 2017 lecture notes.
5. A. Cohen, G. Moore, P. Nelson & J. Polchinski, [Nucl. Phys. B267 (1986) 143](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(86)90148-3); Chapter 2.
6. C.M. Hull & J.-L. Vazquez-Bello, [arXiv:hep-th/9308022](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9308022); Chapter 2.
7. P. van Nieuwenhuizen, [Lecture notes](http://www.dkpi.at/event/lectures-peter-van-nieuwenhuizen/).

--

$^1$ We ignore boundary terms. Effectively this means that we impose pertinent boundary conditions, and limit gauge symmetry to the bulk.

$^2$ The $\epsilon$-dependence in the BFV action (37) comes only from the gauge-fixing fermion (38). The $\epsilon$-dependence can be removed via redefinition

$$ \epsilon B~\longrightarrow~  B, \qquad  
\epsilon\bar{C}~\longrightarrow~  \bar{C}, \qquad 
\frac{\chi}{\epsilon} ~\longrightarrow~ \chi, \qquad 
\frac{\xi}{\epsilon^2} ~\longrightarrow~ \xi  .\tag{48} $$

In the limit $\epsilon\to 0$, the infinities on the rhs. of the Poisson brackets (31) should be interpreted as zero, i.e. the corresponding canonical variables become decoupled.

Comment: Comment to the answer (v12): The expression (20) vanishes in WL [dimensional regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_regularization), cf. Ref. 3.

Comment: Minor correction. We assume $r=0$ for simplicity. There is a gauge-for-gauge symmetry $\delta C=C_0$ ghost-zeromode. Define BRST transformation ${\bf s}C=\gamma_0$ ghost-for-ghost zeromode.

Comment: Comments for later: It seems the BRST transformation (16) for $x^{\mu}$ should transform into $p$ rather than $\dot{x}$. (Of course, that's the same on-shell.) This is precisely what is done in eq. (36).

Comment: Comments for later: The abelianization $r=0$ (changing the gauge algebra) may alter the partition function, even for Hamiltonian BFV.