# Why should it be allowed to set the einbein to unity?

Tags: mass, lagrangian-formalism, dimensional-analysis, action, gauge

The Polyakov action for a massive free point particle with worldline $\gamma$ is given by

$$ S[\gamma] = \frac{1}{2}\int_\gamma e \biggl(\frac{1}{e^2}\dot{x}^2 - m^2\biggr)\mathrm{d}\tau $$

where $e$ is the so-called *einbein*, which may be interpreted as a one-dimensional worldline metric $\sqrt{g_{\tau\tau}}$. As is discussed, for example, [in this P.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130867/50583), it is often casually stated that the reparametrization invariance of the Polyakov action allows us to (gauge-)fix $e = 1$.

Yet, by inspection, we see that the einbein must have mass dimension $-1$, and indeed, it is also sometimes set to be $e = \frac{1}{m}$ when dealing with massive particles. The question is therefore:

Why would it be allowed to set a *dimensionful quantity* to unity? Would we not have to introduce some kind of mass scale (which may drop out of physical observables)? Note that there is *no* natural mass scale in our theory if $m = 0$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting the einbein to $1$ corresponds to a diffeomorphism of the metric, as the einbein is given by $e_{\tau\tau}=\sqrt{g_{\tau\tau}}$, which can be easily deduced from the fact that a the vielbein is given as the transformation coefficients from the coordinate basis to a non-coordinate basis. Hence, the dimensionality of the einbein depends on that of the metric. From the requirement that the metric has mass dimension $-2$, it can only follow that the einbein has mass dimension $-1$. A reparametrization corresponds to multiplication with a dimensionless number, i.e. setting the einbein to unity actually means setting its numerical value to $1$ while keeping its dimension. No new mass scale has to be introduced.