# Does the Harmonic conjugate of the Hamiltonian have to do with the Lagrangian?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-numbers, analyticity

Say, we have a Hamiltonian $H(x,p)$. We find a function $G(x,p)$ such that the function $H(x,p)+iG(x,p)$ has a complex derivative.
$G$ is then the harmonic conjugate of $H$.

Since the change in $H(x,p)$ in time-evolution is 0 (assuming energy is conserved), the changes in $G(x,p)$ should be extremised during time evolution, because the time evolution is orthogonal to the gradient of $H(x,p)$, and hence is along the gradient of $G(x,p)$. This sounds a lot like the Lagrangian (as the action, just like $\delta G(x,p)$, is extremised during time evolution). Does $G$ have anything to do with the lagrangian? What is $G$? Why are we never taught about it?

Comment: Are you implicitly assuming that $H(x,p)$ is a [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function)?? That seems like a very restrictive and unphysical assumption.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. I thought any two-varibale function had a Harmonic conjugate which could be found by integration. Is the Hamiltonian not nice enough for that?

Comment: This question here might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316884/