# Can somebody explain why the action in the picture is true?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, action, geodesics, point-particles

[image]

I can provide the resource for where this is from. Can somebody explain how to get this expression?

Comment: *"I can provide the resource for where this is from"* Please do. It's of no use to state that you *can* provide the source and then not provide it.

Answer (score 1):

it is not "derived" from anywhere. It is coooked up so that the resulting equations of motion are the ones that are desired. The action is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's action (1.2) can be viewed as the "point-particle Polyakov action" in the  $e=1/m$ gauge, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130867/2451) Phys.SE. (Here $g^{\text{OP}}_{\mu\nu}=m^2g_{\mu\nu}$.)
2. Alternatively, one can argue that the Lagrangian for a massive point particle/geodesic can be defined with or without a square root, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44947/2451) Phys.SE posts.