# Hamilton-Jacobi equation in context of GR

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics

I'm reading a paper in which the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is stated as $$-\frac{\partial S}{\partial \tau} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha S \partial_\beta S,\tag{1}$$ where $\tau$ is the proper time. This is the first time I've come across the Hamilton-Jacobi equation in the context of GR.

I understand the Hamilton-Jacobi equation in the classical sense (see e.g. wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) but I can't seem to generalize this to the expression above in GR-terms.

Comment: The Hamilton-Jacobi equation *for what system*? A free point particle?

Comment: It's in terms of deriving the Johannsen metric, which is a continuous deviation from the Kerr metric. It is just postulated here so I'm quite clueless

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Answer (score 1):

OP's eq. (1) is evidently the Hamilton-Jacobi (HJ) equation for the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}p_{\alpha}p_{\beta}$ of a relativistic point particle in the $e=1$ gauge, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509818/2451) related Phys.SE post.