# Covariant quantization of an interacting relativistic particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, covariance, quantization, brst

A method of covariant quantization for a free relativistic particle appears in the first part of some introductory string theory texts (Tong, Zwiebach,...). None of them (as far as I hae seen) give an explicit worked out example of how to treat an *interacting* theory of relativistic particles in this formalism, despite most of them mentioning that it can be done.

I am looking for any reference where this kind of quantization is explicitly developed for an interacting particle theory, preferably showing some results that can be compared with the standard quantum field theory approach.

Comment: Huh ? I don't understand your question. If you want a theory that contains multiple particles, you use QFT. If these particles are relativistic, then you use relativistic QFT.  What exactly do you want to know ?

Comment: FWIW, the Lagrangian BV and the Hamiltonian BFV covariant BRST quantization of the free relativistic point-particle is discussed in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451) Phys.SE post.