# What is the major difference between Dirac and BRST quantization of point particle?

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, gauge-invariance, constrained-dynamics, brst

I have derived the action for the bosonic point particle and now I want to quantize it but there are two formalism: one is Dirac and the other one is BRST. I want to know what is the major difference between these two mechanisms?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "major difference", given that both approaches must yield the same final theory, else one of them is not different, but simply wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) For a general Hamiltonian gauge theory,

1. the Dirac/Bergmann analysis with the Gupta-Bleuler condition ("old quantization method")

is generalized/refined by

2. the Hamiltonian BRST quantization ("new quantization method") with a nilpotent BRST charge $Q$. Physical states are described by the BRST-cohomology.

If the gauge algebra structure is complicated enough, the old method is insufficient.

II) For the BRST formulation of a point particle, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/114903/2451).

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.