# How does Susskind get this fourth equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, gauge-invariance

I'm studying Friedman and Susskind's *Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory*.

In Lecture 6, they derive
$$m{dU_\mu\over d\tau}=eF_{\mu\nu}U^\nu,\tag{6.33}$$
but only when $\mu=1, 2, 3$. ($F_{\mu\nu}$ stands for $\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$.) To prove that this equation also holds for $\mu=0$, they give the following argument.

> If the equations are Lorentz invariant, and the three space comonents of a certain 4-vector are equal to the three space components of some other 4-vector, then we know *automatically* that their zeroth components (the time components) must also match.

I can see that both, the LHS and the RHS of the above equation are 4-vectors. But I don't see how the equality of the LHS and the RHS for $\mu=1,2,3$ implies their equality for $\mu=0$. Please help me prove it.

---

I found that this question has been asked [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377189/231957) on SE. But I couldn't understand the posted answer (by Prahar) there—it used gauge invariance concepts and I'm not yet familiar with that. But I'll appreciate if someone can explain me enough to understand that answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to get the fourth component of EOM in a relativistic formulation of a charged particle in an electromagnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377189/2451) Consider to place a bounty rather than ask the same question again.

Comment: @Qmechanic Okay, but can I ask a question to help me understand what Prahar wrote there? Or would that too be taken down?

Comment: @Qmechanic Or can *you* help me understand this? Since you seem to know... As you said in your last comment in that post, I saw Susskind's lecture and couldn't get it there...

Comment: Did you understand section 1 of my answer?

Comment: I understand the statement, but not your proposed proof...

Comment: @Qmechanic Please do help. If you’ve time :)

Comment: What don't you understand in my proof?

Comment: @Qmechanic Oh, I just got that! You argue that since $W$ was the zero vector, its transformed version will be zero, and since the three transformed components of $W$ equal the corresponding transformed components of $V$, we get that the $V^0$ must be zero otherwise some of its components upon transformation would have been nonzero.

Comment: I'm so sorry for causing all this confusion, but thanks a lot for your time!