# Functional and total variations in einbein action

Tags: string-theory, variational-principle, action, functional-derivatives

I'm currently studying String theory by Becker& Becker, Schwarz textbook. The exercise 2.3 consists in verifying diffeomorphism invariance of einbein action wich is given by

$$ S_0 = \frac{1}{2} \int d\tau (e^{-1}\dot{X}^2 - m^2e), \ e= e(\tau) \tag1 $$

such that under a diffeomorphism $\tau'({\tau}), \ e(\tau) d\tau = e'(\tau')d\tau'$.

At the beginning of solution, the author states that the embedding functions $X^\mu: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ transform as scalar fields $(X'^\mu(\tau') = X^\mu(\tau))$under diffeomorphisms, in particular, "infinitesimal" diffeomorphisms $\tau'(\tau) = \tau - \xi(\tau)$ wich is totally reasonable to me.

The problem is that the author also states that the first-order variation on the functions should be $\delta X^\mu = X'^\mu(\tau) - X^\mu(\tau)=\xi(\tau)\dot{X}^\mu$. As I understand, this is a *functional variation*, such that the *total variation* should be $\delta_T X^\mu = \delta X^\mu - \xi(\tau)\dot{X}^\mu= 0$. Why did the author ignored the coordinate change in $X^mu$ in order to compute later the variation of the action?

There is also a problem concerning the difference between functional and total variations: the author uses the property $e(\tau) d\tau = e'(\tau')d\tau'$ to obtain

$$\delta e = \frac{d}{d\tau} (\xi e). \tag2$$ From my computations, I've obtained the above result and that the total variation of $e$ should be $\delta_T e= \dot{\xi}e$.  Why are only functional variations used instead of total variations in order to show that $(1)$ is diff. invariant?

The results mentioned above can be found in *Basic Concepts in String Theory* by Blumenhagen, and the classical *WSG Superstring Theory* textbook.

Since the results are present in three separate books, I suppose I must be making a serious mistake. My knowledge of variational calculus can be summarized in chapter 4 of *Classical Fields* by R. Aldrovandi and J. G. Pereira.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Infinitesimal transformations for a relativistic particle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the variation of $X^\mu(\tau)$ under worldline reparameterizations I'm not sure I understood what you are confused about, but the way it is derived is by noticing that under the reparameterization $\tau\mapsto \tau'(\tau)$ the fields transform as ${X'}^\mu(\tau')=X^\mu(\tau)$.

In that case considering one infinitesimal reparameterization $\tau'(\tau)=\tau-\xi(\tau)$ we have that since $\xi$ is infinitesimal $\tau(\tau')=\tau'+\xi(\tau')$ and therefore $$X'^\mu(\tau')=X^\mu(\tau'+\xi(\tau')).$$

Now denoting $\tau'$ as $\tau$ in the above equation and Taylor expanding the RHS we have $$X'^\mu(\tau)=X^\mu(\tau)+\xi(\tau)\dfrac{dX^\mu}{d\tau}\Longrightarrow \delta X^\mu(\tau)=\xi(\tau)\partial_\tau X^\mu$$

where in the last step we recognize $\delta X^\mu = X'^\mu(\tau) - X^\mu(\tau)$, the difference *at same $\tau$* between transformed and unstransformed fields.

About the einbein it works in the same way. In fact $e(\tau)d\tau=e'(\tau')d\tau'$ implies the one-form transformation law $$e(\tau)\dfrac{d\tau}{d\tau'}=e'(\tau')$$
and writing $\tau =\tau'+\xi(\tau')$

$$e(\tau'+\xi(\tau'))(1+\partial_{\tau'}\xi(\tau'))=e'(\tau')$$

Now just denoting $\tau'$ as $\tau$ and Taylor expanding the einbein on the LHS gives $$(e(\tau)+\partial_\tau e(\tau)\xi(\tau))(1+\partial_{\tau}\xi(\tau))=e'(\tau)$$

fully expanding the LHS and discarding second order terms in $\xi(\tau)$ it is

$$e(\tau)+e(\tau)\partial_\tau\xi+\partial_\tau e(\tau) \xi(\tau)=e'(\tau)\Longrightarrow \delta e(\tau)=\partial_\tau (e(\tau)\xi(\tau))$$

where we again recognized the variation $\delta e(\tau)=e'(\tau)-e(\tau)$ as the difference *at same $\tau$* of transformed and untransformed fields, and where we recognized a derivative of a product in the process.