# Reparametrization invariance of Einbein action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, gauge-theory

I'm going through David Tong's online [lecture notes on String theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0333). At the end of section 1.1.2, where he introduces the einbein action

$$S=\frac{1}{2} \int d\tau (e^{-1}\dot{X}^2-em^2),\tag{1.8}$$

he claims that it retains reparametrization invariance through:

$$\tau \rightarrow \tilde{\tau}-\eta(\tau) \ \ , \ \ \delta e = \frac{d}{d \tau}(\eta(\tau)e) \ \ , \ \ \delta X^{\mu}=\frac{dX^{\mu}}{d\tau}\eta(\tau).\tag{1.10}$$

Can anyone help on how to prove invariance under these transformations? This is what I've worked out:

$$\tilde{S}=\frac{1}{2} \int d\tilde{\tau} (\tilde{e}^{-1}\dot{\tilde{X}}^2-\tilde{e}m^2)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int d\tau (1-\eta'(\tau)) \left(\frac{1}{e+\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta(\tau)e)} \eta^{2}(\tau)\dot{X}^2-\left(e+\frac{d}{d\tau}(\eta(\tau)e)\right)m^2 \right).$$

I'm not sure how to get $S$ again. The denominator is annoying.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451