Infinitesimal transformation acting on einbein in Polchinski's String Theory
From Polchinski's String Theory:

Point-particle example
Let us consider an example, the point particles. Expanding out the condensed notation above, the local symmetry is coordinate reparameterization $\delta \tau(\tau)$, so the index $\alpha$ just becomes $\tau$ and a basis of infinitesimal transformations is $\delta_{\tau_1} \tau(\tau) = \delta (\tau - \tau_{1})$. These acts on the fields as
$$\delta_{\tau_1} X^{\mu}(\tau) = \delta(\tau - \tau_1)\partial_{\tau}X^{\mu}(\tau), \quad \delta_{\tau_1} e(\tau) = - \partial_{\tau}[\delta(\tau - \tau_1)e(\tau)].
\tag{4.2.19}$$

Why does the transformation act differently when applied to $X$ and when applied to $e$?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114862/2451
