# Finding geodesics: Lagrangian vs Hamiltonian

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, variational-principle, geodesics

I have a question referring to how to compute geodesics of a given spacetime (say, Kerr).

I know that the direct way is via the geodesic equation

$$\frac{d^{2}x^{\mu}}{d\lambda^{2}}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\kappa}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\kappa}~=~0.$$

But also read that one can write down the geodesic equations using the Lagrangian formalism. From what I have seen so far, there are two approaches: either to write down the Euler-Lagrange equations with Lagrangian

$$L~=~\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}.$$

and then Euler-Lagrange equations are exactly the geodesic equations.

OR: write down the Hamiltonian equations using the Lagrangian above, and then use *those* equations as the geodesic equations.

My question: are Euler-Lagrange and Hamiltonian approaches fully equivalent when it comes to writing down the geodesic equations? Does one have advantage over the other?

Answer (score 6):

They are all equivalent. The answer to your other question is: the Hamiltonian approach usually works best.

Geodesics can be defined a few ways, since the connection of spacetime is taken to be Levi-Civita.

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ denote spacetime $\mathcal{M}$ with metric $g$ and $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to M,t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ be a curve on $\mathcal{M}$. If $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection on spacetime, then the *geodesic equation* is
$$\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=0,$$
where $\dot\gamma$ is the tangent vector of $\gamma$. Some manipulations can bring this into the form given in the OP. On the other hand, we can define the *length functional*
$$\ell [\gamma]:=\int_a^b\sqrt{-g(\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
(The negative appears because $\gamma$ is usually taken to be timelike for GR purposes.) Then it may be shown that
$$\frac{\delta\ell}{\delta\gamma}=0\Longleftrightarrow\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma=0.$$
So  the geodesic problem of GR is actually an Euler-Lagrange type problem with Lagrangian $L=\sqrt{-g(\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)}$.

We can also get a Hamiltonian approach. We first note that the *energy functional*
$$E[\gamma]=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^bg(\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)\,\mathrm{d}t$$
has identical Euler-Lagrange equations as the length functional. Proof: Let $D$ be the operator $$Df=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
where $f=f(x,\dot x,t)$, so that $Df=0$ is the Euler-Lagrange equation for $f$. Then a short computation shows that $D\ell=\ell\cdot DE$, so $D\ell=0\implies DE=0$. We note that $H:=\frac{1}{2}g(\dot\gamma,\dot\gamma)$ is reminiscent of the $\frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{v}^2$ term of the classical free particle Hamiltonian. (Hence the name energy functional.)

We can do this more fancily on the cotangent bundle $T^*\mathcal{M}$. Locally trivialize the cotangent bundle in a chart, so we have coordinates $(x^\mu,p_\mu)$. Then put
$$H(x,p):=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}(x)p_\mu p_\nu.$$
The Hamiltonian equations
$$\dot x^\mu=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_\mu},\quad \dot p^\mu=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x^\mu}$$
are equivalent to the geodesic equation. 
The flow obtained from these equations is a Hamiltonian flow.

It turns out that the first Hamilton approach is very useful. It is quite easy to vary the integral $E[\gamma]$. This, combined with the Killing method for obtaining first integrals of the geodesic equation, make for a better strategy than computing the Christoffel symbols and solving the equations outright.

It should be noted that there is another method for solving the geodesic equations: apply the methods of Hamilton-Jacobi theory to the Hamiltonian system described above. This method is used in N. Straumann, *General Relativity* (2013) to find the geodesics of Kerr spacetime. See also V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classial Mechanics* (1989) for more on Hamiltonian systems in general.

It should be noted that the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian described above are not actually Legendre transforms of each other.

Answer (score 4):

1. The Hessian matrix
   $$\tag{1} \frac{\partial^2 L_0}{\partial\dot{x}^{\mu}\partial\dot{x}^{\nu}}~=~2g_{\mu\nu}(x), \qquad \det g_{\mu\nu}(x)~\neq~0,$$
   of OP's Lagrangian 
   $$\tag{2} L_0~=~g_{\mu\nu}(x)~\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}$$
   is non-singular. This means that the [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) is regular, and therefore that the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations are equivalent, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105912/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. However, since OP mentions [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic), which extremize lengths of curves, it should be mentioned that the underlying Lagrangian is actually the square root Lagrangian
   $$\tag{3} L~=~-\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}(x)~\dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}}$$
   rather than OP's Lagrangian (2).
3. The equivalence between the two Lagrangians (2) and (3) is discussed in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) Phys.SE post in the Riemannian case.
4. Interestingly, the Hessian matrix of the square root Lagrangian (3) is in fact singular, i.e. the Legendre transformation is singular, and there appears a constraint. (This is related to the worldline reparametrization invariance of the corresponding action for (3).) However, one may still show the equivalence between the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulations via e.g. Dirac-Bergmann analysis. This is e.g. done in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post.