# Hamilton or Hamilton-Jacobi formalism with Hamiltonian equal to zero

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics

I have the Lagrange function:

$$L=\sqrt{\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}{-y}}.\tag{1}$$

The energy is then:

$$H=\dot{x}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}+\dot{y}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}}-L=0.\tag{2}$$
Can I somehow apply in this case the Hamilton or Hamilton-Jacobi formalism to find the motion?

Comment: If $H=0$ then everything is super simple, everything is constant (just look at the Hamilton equations). Essentially you've already solved the Hamilton-Jacobi equation.

Comment: What are the canonical momenta?

Comment: Well, but I know that for the Lagrangian L the solution is a motion along a cycloid. So, not everything is constatnt. How to obtain such a solution from the Hamiltonian that is zero?

Answer (score 1):

1. OP's Lagrangian (1) is the square root Lagrangian for a massive relativistic point particle (or equivalently, geodesics) in a curved space with metric
   $${\bf g}~=~\frac{\mathrm{d}x\odot \mathrm{d}x+ \mathrm{d}y\odot \mathrm{d}y}{-y}, \qquad y~<~0 .\tag{1}$$
2. The square root Lagrangian (1) has worldline reparametrization invariance, i.e. gauge symmetry. As a result, the Lagrangian energy function $h(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y})$ [and the Hamiltonian $H(x,y,p_x,p_y)$ in the corresponding Hamiltonian formalism, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post] vanish.
3. The easiest way to proceed is to consider the corresponding non-square root Lagrangian, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149082/2451) Phys.SE post. Then the Legendre transformation, Hamiltonian & Hamilton-Jacobi theory are in principle straightforward to set up.

Comment: OK. But my problem is like follows. The Lagrangian describes motion along cycloid (this can be shown on the basis of Lagrange equations). Can I reproduce this result within the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism?