# Hamiltonian formulation of the geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, geodesics

I am using the Hamilton's formulation of the geodesic equation in order to obtain geodesic equations in terms of the particle's coordinates and the conjugate momenta. Now, I am figuring out a way to distinguish timelike, null and spacelike geodesics. How do I treat timelike geodesics in particular when using the Hamiltonian formulation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451 The answer therein also works for light-like geodesics.