# Applications and limitations of the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, gauge-invariance

It was my understanding that the Hamiltonian formalism was inadequate to describe systems that are invariant under time reparametrization or that have gauge symmetries.

However, I see in [Classical Dynamics by Jorge V. José and Eugene J. Saletan](https://books.google.es/books?id=Eql9dRQDgvQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=jos%C3%A9%20saletan&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIjrei0sfmAhWZDGMBHVdxDzQQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=jos%C3%A9%20saletan&f=false), that both a relativistic particle and a particle under an electromagnetic potential are described using the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism, dealing the right equations of motion.

I wonder why does this work: Are there systems that can be treated with by Hamilton-Jacobi formalism but yield false results when treated by Hamilton?  Is there a way to adequately treat systems with the mentioned invariances through Hamiltonian mechanics? If so, are their Hamiltonians always of the form $H=T+V$?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is meant by "Hamilton formalism" vs "Hamilton-Jacobi formalism", but the Hamilton-Jacobi equation is a first order PDE whose characteristics are given by Hamilton's equations. Solving them is mathematically equivalent. It is true that Hamilton's formalism (unlike Lagrange's) does not have a good generalization to gauge fields, but motion of particles in external fields is far from that.

Comment: Which page in J&S?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Hamiltonian formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) also works for gauge systems, although one has to introduce [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(classical_mechanics)) (and possibly the corresponding Lagrange multipliers), see e.g. Ref. 1. For the relativistic point particle, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. In fact the [Hamilton-Jacobi equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) is derived from the Hamiltonian formalism, not the other way around.
3. The Hamiltonian $H$ is not always of the form $T+U$. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451) Phys.SE post for the corresponding Lagrangian question.

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.