# Variational principle and the medium equation for photon paths in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, geometric-optics, variational-principle, plasma-physics

I am reading a 2015 paper by Rogers on [Frequency-dependent effects of gravitational lensing within plasma](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06790). He gives the relation between the components of the photon four-momentum and the refractive index of the medium,
$$n^2=1+\frac{p_i p^i}{\left(p_j V^j\right)^2}\tag{3}$$
where $p^i$ is the linear momentum of the photon, $V^j$ is the velocity of the plasma medium, and $n$ is the refractive index of the medium.

He then goes on to write

> We describe photon paths through the plasma in the Schwarzschild space–time by the Hamiltonian in the geometric optics limit. Using the variational principle and the medium equation we have
> $$
> H\left(x^i, p_i\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left[g^{i j} p_i p_j+\left(n^2-1\right)\left(p_j V^j\right)^2\right]=0\,.\tag{4}
> $$

Please, can you explain how the above equation is derived?

Comment: I cannot say where the 1/2 enters, but inside the []'s is just the first expression you showed.  The metric tensor $g^{ij}$ is merely used to contract the dyad $p_{i} p_{j}$, I think.  In your first expression, it's just the inner product which gives a scalar.  A GR expert may know more but it looks like there's nothing sneaky going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We can [wlog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) consider a reference frame where the plasma medium is static, i.e. $V^{\mu}$ has only a temporal component:
   $$-1 = ||V||^2~=~g_{00} V^0V^0 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad V^0 ~=~ (-g_{00})^{-1/2}. \tag{A}$$
2. We assume that the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ does not have any mixed temporal-spatial components.
3. Eq. (3) in Ref. 1 goes to the center of the [Abraham-Minkowski controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Minkowski_controversy)$^1$. Eq. (3) is equivalent to Minkowski's proposal that the photon 3-wavevector in a refractive medium is
   $$|{\bf k}|~=~n\frac{\omega}{c},\tag{1.10}$$
   cf. eq. (1.10) in Ref. 2. Equivalently$^2$
   $$  n^2~\stackrel{(1.10)}{=}~\frac{g_{ab}k^ak^b}{-g_{00}(k^0)^2}
   ~\stackrel{p=\hbar k}{=}~1+\frac{p^2}{(p^0\sqrt{-g_{00}})^2} ,\qquad 
   p^2~:=~ g_{\mu\nu}p^{\mu}p^{\nu},\tag{B}$$
   which is eq. (3).
4. The [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) $n$ is by definition the reciprocal [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity). Assuming no dispersion, we can identify it with the reciprocal [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity)
   $$|{\bf v}|~=~\frac{c}{n}.\tag{C}$$
   Equivalently
   $$\frac{1}{n^2}~\stackrel{(C)}{=}~\frac{g_{ab}\dot{x}^a\dot{x}^b}{-g_{00}(\dot{x}^0)^2},\qquad 
   \dot{x}^{\mu} ~=~\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}.\tag{D}$$
5. Eq. (1.10) and the speed of light condition (C) suggests that
   in adapted coordinates
   $$ \dot{x}^a~=~ep^a, \qquad \dot{x}^0~=~ en^2p^0, \tag{E}$$
   where $e$ is an einbein/[Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). In covariant form eq. (E) reads
   $$ \frac{\dot{x}^{\mu}}{e}~=~p^{\mu} -(n^2-1)V^{\mu} (p\cdot V)~=~G^{\mu\nu} p_{\nu}, \tag{F}$$
   where we have introduced an effective metric tensor
   $$ G_{\mu\nu}~=~g_{\mu\nu} + (1-n^{-2}) V_{\mu}V_{\nu}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad  G^{\mu\nu}~=~g^{\mu\nu} - (n^2-1) V^{\mu}V^{\nu}. \tag{G} $$
6. We next consider the Hamiltonian Lagrangian
   $$L_H~=~p\cdot \dot{x}- H,\tag{H}$$
   where the Hamiltonian is of the form *Lagrange multiplier times constraint*
   $$ H~:=~\frac{e}{2} p_{\mu}G^{\mu\nu}p_{\nu}
   ~=~\frac{e}{2}\left( p^2 - (n^2-1) (p\cdot V)^2 \right).\tag{I}$$
   In the gauge $e=1$ the Hamiltonian $H$ becomes eq. (17) in Ref. 3 and eq. (4) in Ref. 1. Note that eq. (4) contains a sign mistake in the second term.
7. The EL equations of $L_H$ wrt. $p_{\mu}$ and $e$ reproduce eq. (F) and eq. (1.10), respectively, as they should.
8. The Hamiltonian action principle
   $$ S_H ~=~\int d\lambda~L_H \tag{J}$$
   agrees with the variational principle (16) in Ref. 3.
9. It is straightforward to integrate out $p_{\mu}$ and/or $e$ to arrive at corresponding Lagrangian formulations, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451) Phys.SE post. The light trajectories are null-like geodesics wrt. the $G_{\mu\nu}$ metric.

References:

1. A. Rogers, *Frequency-dependent effects of gravitational lensing within plasma,* [arXiv:1505.06790](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06790).
2. S.M. Barnett & R. Loudon, *The enigma of optical momentum in a medium,* [Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society A Mathematical Physical and Engineering Sciences 368 (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2009.0207).
3. O.Yu. Tsupko & G.S. Bisnovatyi-Kogan, *Gravitational lensing in plasma: Relativistic images at homogeneous plasma,* [arXiv:1305.7032](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.7032).

--

$^1$ Ref. 2 claims in section 5 that the resolution of the controversy is that the Abraham 3-momentum is the kinetic momentum of the light in the medium, while the Minkowski 3-momentum is the canonical momentum.

$^2$ Let $\mu,\nu\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ be spacetime indices while $a,b\in\{1,2,3\}$ are spatial indices.

Comment: Thanks, 1. please could you let me know where I can read more about the speed of light condition. 2. Also, is $n^{−2}$ in (G) meant to be $n^2$? 3. Additionally, is $k^\mu=p^\mu$?

Comment: 1+3. I updated the answer. 2. No.