# Hamiltonian of the relativistic point particle

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

It is unclear to me why the Hamiltonian of a relativistic particle is zero. I know that, given a relativistic free particle, I can write the Lagrangian of it in this way: $$\mathcal{L} = mc^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$ from which, using the Legendre transformation, one can write $$\mathcal{H} = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}};$$ the corresponding action is then $$S = -mc^2\int ds,\qquad ds = cdt\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}.$$
Nevertheless, if I write the action in this form: $$S = -mc\int_{\tau_1}^{\tau_2}\sqrt{-\eta_{\mu v} \dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{v}}d\tau$$ then applying the Legendre transformation, one gets $H = 0$.
Being an undergrad, I haven't seen this in any class yet, but I thought that maybe it has to do with the parametrization.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90552/2451